# I am not able open dialog box on clicking a button here is the code

Tags: jquery, asp.net, dialog

asp.net code

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnnext" runat="server" Text="Update" onclick="btnnext_Click"  />

<div id= "DisplayEnteredDetails" >

<asp:GridView ID="grdDisplayEnteredDetails" runat="server"   >
                    </asp:GridView> 
</div>
```

calling function

```
  <script type="Text/javascript">
    $(function () {
     $('#DisplayEnteredDetails').dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 600,
                height: 500,
                hide: 'Transfer',
                open: function (type, data) {
                    $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
                }
            });
     // Dialog button
            $('#ctl00_Main_btnnext').click(function () {
                $('#DisplayEnteredDetails').dialog('open');
                return false;
            });


        });   
    </script>
```

i gave the link in master page like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/styles/StyleSheet.css" />
    <link href="jquery/css/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

same code works in other project but not in my application

Comment: what error does it show?

Comment: Not showing any error

Comment: anything in console? Script error?

Comment: add jquery library and ui on your master page reference

Comment: Replace `<script type="Text/javascript">` with just `<script>` and check.

Comment: i added the references

Comment: @ShodhanHuli : you only include the css, not the js

Answer (score 0):

Replace `<script type="Text/javascript">` with just `<script>` and check. The script tag should have all small letters. So, `<script type="text/javascript">` or simply `<script>` should work.

Or else you may have forgotten to add jquery Ui reference in your html. (assuming, as it is not visible in your provided code)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: @ShodhanHuli where are you adding the js files? please post that code too.

Comment: <link href="jquery/css/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> this is the reference only i gave in master page same reference works in other project

Comment: @ShodhanHuli that is `css` file. you need to add also jquery and jquery UI references.

Comment: C:\Users\Vantage Agore\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\odonovaTest\jquery i just copy pasted j query folder into my application and gave reference nothing else i did

Comment: @ShodhanHuli `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>` add  this line above the `link` tags in html.

Comment: These are the references i gave                                                               <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    
     
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.ui.draggable.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.ui.resizable.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.ui.dialog.js"></script>

Comment: @ShodhanHuli remove those or make them comment and add the script lines which I mentioned above. You should really look for a beginners guide.

Comment: If i give this link without internet also it works fine right?

Comment: @ShodhanHuli No, download the js files on your local disk and replace the website link with your local disk path. Then you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

To display a dialog using jQuery you need two things:

1. [Download jQuery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js)
2. [Download jQuery UI](http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js)

Place these two files in your project and add a reference to them on the page/master page:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Here a complete example that works:

P.S: Remember to change the id of the button in the script to the correct value

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>Dialog</title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#DisplayEnteredDetails').dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 600,
                height: 500,
                hide: 'Transfer',
                open: function (type, data) {
                    $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
                }
            });
            // Dialog button
            $('#ctl00_Main_btnnext').click(function () {
                $('#DisplayEnteredDetails').dialog('open');
                return false;
            });
        });  
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="ctl00_Main_btnnext" runat="server" Text="Update" OnClick="btnnext_Click" />
    <div id="DisplayEnteredDetails" style="border:1px solid #2d2d2d;">
        <asp:GridView ID="grdDisplayEnteredDetails" runat="server">
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```